# Upgrading from Spring 3.2.1 to 3.2.13 gives 404 on static resources

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

We'd like to upgrade our Spring dependency, but are having issues with resources not being found by the server. No code-changes have been made, this works fine in `3.2.1`.

We register the handler like this

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/kjernejournal.html").addResourceLocations("/kjernejournal.html").setCachePeriod(0);
}
```

Log has

```
o.s.w.s.h.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/kjernejournal.html] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
```

But this fails later on, with the following error.

```
12:07:04.520 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapping [/kjernejournal.html] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler@75288586] and 1 interceptor
12:07:04.520 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Last-Modified value for [/hpp-webapp/kjernejournal.html] is: -1
12:07:04.520 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] DEBUG o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler - Trying relative path [/kjernejournal.html] against base location: ServletContext resource [/kjernejournal.html]
12:07:04.520 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] DEBUG o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler - No matching resource found - returning 404
```

The file does exist in the root of the WAR-file.

Any idea on where to begin?

Comment: If it already exists then you don't need the resource handler. You need to enable the `DefaultServletHandler`.

Comment: @M.Deinum Ah, that seems to work fine. Thanks! Any way to add `cachePeriod`? We'd like to `no-cache` them

Comment: You could do that with a filter, that wouldn't work with the default handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the problem.

When we register like

```
registry.addResourceHandler("/kjernejournal.html").addResourceLocations("/").setCachePeriod(0);
```

Instead of

```
registry.addResourceHandler("/kjernejournal.html").addResourceLocations("/kjernejournal.html").setCachePeriod(0);
```

It works fine. So the problem seems to be that `resourceLocations` pointed to a file instead of a directory. From `ResourceHandlerRegistration` JavaDoc:

> Add one or more resource locations from which to serve static content. Each location must point to a valid directory.

Weird that it worked before, though...